# Compile time operators

Tags: c++, operators, metaprogramming

Could someone please list a all compile time operators in available in C++?

Comment: All operators can potentially be evaluated at compile-time (e.g. constant folding).  But I guess you mean things like `sizeof`?

Comment: Maybe you could seed the list with an example of what you consider to be a "compile-time operator." I'm not aware of such a term in C++.

Comment: "Operators" aren't compile time, the values they operate on potentiality are.

Comment: @GMan so why I read everywhere that sizeof is a compile time operator and typeid isn't?

Comment: `sizeof` operates on things that are known at compile-time; this isn't necessarily the case with `typeid`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two operators in C++ whose result can always be determined at compile-time, regardless of the operand(s), and those are `sizeof`[1] and `::`[2].

Of course there are plenty of particular uses of other operators that can be resolved at compile-time, for example those listed in the standard for *integer constant expressions*.

[1] C99, unlike C++, has variable length array types. `sizeof` applied to a VLA can't be determined at compile-time. Some C++ compilers provide VLAs as an extension.

[2] that is, it can be determined at compile time what entity is the result of the expression. If the entity is an object, then the object's value is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such term in the standard.

But here's a list of all operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B (I'm sure there are others...).  It should be fairly easy to categorise them one way or the other.