# Compile time operators in C

Tags: c, compile-time

I'm familiar with only one compile time operator in C - `sizeof`. Are there any others that I as a programmer should be aware of?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114982/compile-time-operators

Comment: C++ isn't a strict superset of C though

Comment: then it's only sizeof, as Nic indicated in his answer. Keep in mind that any operator can be compile-time when you provide constants to it (e.g.`4*8` or `2<<5` will be replaced with 32 at run time).

Comment: I can think of `-` in `&a[constant1]-&a[constant2]`, where `a` is an array (or a pointer).

Comment: @Alex: that's a particular expression involving `-`, that could be evaluated at compile time because of some useful property of the operands. It's a different thing from `-` itself being a "compile-time operator"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `sizeof` that I'm aware, although in C99 sizeof cannot be done at compile time for variable length arrays (VLAs).

Comment: Beat me to it, I just noticed this was C-only and removed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're grasping for but missing the terminology to describe is a *constant expression* or *integer constant expression*. The results of certain operators can be (integer) constant expressions if their operands are, and as you've pointed out, the result of `sizeof` can be even if its operand is not constant as long as it's not a VLA. See 6.6 in C99:

http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.6

Answer (score 2):

The new C standard also has `_Alignof` that works similar to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 2):

Although not strictly an *operator*, there is `offsetof`, a macro defined in `stddef.h`. It is used to get the offset of a field member in a `struct`. For example:

```
#include <stddef.h>
struct my_struct
{
  int alpha;
  int beta;
};

int get_offset_to_beta(void)
{
  return offsetof(struct my_struct, beta);
}
```