# operands for sizeof operator

Tags: c, sizeof

I understood result of

```
int nData = 10;
printf("%d", sizeof(nData + 2.0));
```

is "8"

why each result of

```
int nData = 10;
printf("%d", sizeof(nData = 2.0));
printf("%d", sizeof(nData += 2.0));
```

is not 8 but 4? Why `nData` cannot be `12.0` or `12` by `sizeof(nData += 2.0)`?

Comment: the type of the expression counts - ie. `sizeof(double)` vs `sizeof(int)` - which is apparently `8` resp. `4` on your platform.

Comment: related : [assignment inside sizeof function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784553/assignment-inside-sizeof-function-in-c) and [Why is sizeof considered an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-an-operator).

Comment: `%d` is not the correct format string for `sizeof()`.  `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, and the correct format string would be `%zd`.  Per [the C standard, **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**, paragraph 6](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p6): "z Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a `size_t`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because 2.0 is a constant of type `double`, the expression `nData + 2.0` has type `double` as per the "usual arithmetic conversions" specified in section 6.3.1.8 of the C standard:

> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double
>   , the other operand   is   converted,   without   change of type domain,   to   a   type   whose corresponding real type is long double.
>
> **Otherwise,  if  the  corresponding  real  type  of  either  operand 
>   is double , the  other operand   is   converted,   without   change of   type   domain,   to   a   type   whose corresponding real type is
>   double**

So `sizeof` evaluates to the size of a `double`.

In the case of `nData = 2.0` and `nData += 2.0`, each expression has type `int` because that is the type of the left-hand side of the assignment.  So `sizeof` evaluated to the size of an `int`.

Also, the operand of the `sizeof` operator is evaluated for its type only at **compile time**.  This means that any assignment or increment is not evaluated at runtime.  So in your second example, `nData` will still have the value 10 after the two lines that use `sizeof`.  The only time the operand of `sizeof` is evaluated at run time is if the operand is a variable length array.

Comment: The operand of `sizeof` is evaluated if the operand is a variable length array or is a variable length array type. (Saying it is evaluated only if it is a variable length array covers object operands but not type operands.) The way it is phrased in the C standard is “If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated;…”

Answer (score 4):

> *Why `nData` cannot be `12.0` or `12` by `sizeof(nData += 2.0)`?*

Well, `sizeof` is a [compiler time operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8959529/2173917), and it operates on the data type, not the value.

In other words, except when the argument [is VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), the operand of the `sizeof` is not evaluated.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand. If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.

So, in your case,

```
  printf("%d", sizeof(nData + 2.0));   // data == int, 2.0 == double
```

is the same as

```
 printf("%d", sizeof(double));  //  as the resulting "type" of the addition, 
                                //   'int + double' would be  'double'
```

which should better be

```
 printf("%zu", sizeof(double));   //not %d
```

as `sizeof` yields `size_t` type.

Also, regarding the `2.0` being of type `double`, from chapter §6.4.4.2

> A floating constant has a significand part that may be followed by an exponent part and a
>   suffix that specifies its type. The components of the significand part may include a digit
>   sequence representing the whole-number part, followed by a period (.), followed by a
>   digit sequence representing the fraction part. [...]

and

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. [...]

Thus, a constant value like `2.0` has the type `double`.